# TestLoader: Could not find class running CTS

Tags: android, testing, cts

I made my own android test suit to test some functions.
When I try to run this tests in the CTS console I get this error:

```
Test failed to run. Test run failed due to : null
```

In the ADB log, I get this log:

```
TestLoader: Could not find class:"com.xxx.xxxxxx"
```

Should I define the ApplicationTestCase class in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted this line inside the application tag in my manifest and it fixed the issue:

```
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
```